# shift backward images from current image to forward

Tags: jquery

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H86FJ/1/)

I have the following html....

```
<div id="banner">
    <img class="img1" src="" />
    <img class="img2" src="" />
    <img class="img3" src="" />
    <img class="img4" src="" />
</div>
<ul>
    <li class='li1'>one</li>
    <li class='li2'>two</li>
    <li class='li3'>three</li>
    <li class='li4'>four</li>
</ul>
```

When I click on `.li3`(three) the previous images `.img1, .img2` should be shifted to the last i.e. here from `.img4`. The output should be like this:

```
<div id="banner">         
        <img class="img3" src="" />
        <img class="img4" src="" />
        <img class="img1" src="" />
        <img class="img2" src="" />
</div>
```

I have no any idea on this that how could I do this?

**update**

I'm having a little problem from the following provided answer that is I'm using a plugin in there the images are sliding when I use the code answered this appends the images repeatedly when clicked something like this:

```
<div id="banner">         
            <img class="img3" src="" />
            <img class="img4" src="" />
            <img class="img1" src="" />
            <img class="img2" src="" />
            <img class="img2" src="" />
            <img class="img1" src="" />
            <img class="img2" src="" />
            <img class="img3" src="" />
    </div>
```

How could I remove previous one?

Comment: if you click again what should happen

Comment: previous of what.... the same index? did you test the answers below

Comment: if those are working then you should accept the one appropriate for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var $b = $('#banner');
$('ul li').click(function(){
    var idx = $(this).index();
    $b.find('img:lt(' + idx + ')').appendTo($b)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bNK9D/)

Comment: @C-Link you want to give a delay between removing and adding the element

Comment: @C-Link what are you trying to do

Comment: I'm getting problem with the provided answer its appending elements i.e. adding more img again & again when click I'm using a plugin for slider

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
$('.li').click(function(){
    var index = $(this).index(), //get the index of the clicked li.
              $banner = $('#banner');
    $banner.find(".img:gt(" + (index-1) + ")").prependTo($banner); //get all the img greater than its index -1 and prepend it to the parent will reposition them.
 });
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zaeG/)**

For ease of selection just gave a common class for the li's and imgs